# Sorting an array by another array's values using OrderByDescending() does not sort the array

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I'm trying to implement a simple Huffman coding algorithm. I take my input string (ddddbbcccaeeeee) and use it to create 2 arrays, those being a char array called `usedCharacters` and an int array called `characterCounts`. However these arrays need to be sorted by the number of times the character appears in the input string so the Huffman tree can be constructed. I tried using LINQ's OrderByDescending() method like I had seen online:

```
usedCharacters = usedCharacters.OrderByDescending(i => characterCounts).ToArray();
characterCounts = characterCounts.OrderByDescending(i => i).ToArray();
```

The program runs but when I check the results the characters are very obviously still in order as they appear in the input string, meaning no sorting is actually done. On the other hand, `characterCounts` does succesfully sort. I also tried the more commonly seen online solution of `usedCharacters.OrderByDescending(i => characterCounts.IndexOf(i)).ToArray()` but that just causes an index out of bounds exception for reasons I don't fully understand. If anybody could give me some insight into what I'm missing that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Don't use LINQ in this case. The `Array.Sort` method has an overload that will sort an array by keys in another array. Use that.

Comment: The variable 'i' is the rows of the input array usedcharacters.  You are not using 'i'.  You are sorting by a fixed value 'characterCounters'.  Your sort should be something like 'i => i.characterCounts'

Comment: what is type of `usedCharacters`?

Comment: @Chetan The question post states that `usedCharacters` is a _char array_.

Comment: I would suggest doing the ordering based on `( character, character count )` items (pseudo code) _prior to_ splitting them into separate arrays. Something along the lines of [this (fiddle)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iFOOM2).

Comment: Look like a `Dictionary<char,int>` to me.

Comment: If you created a type that had both a character and a count property,. you could have a *single* collection of those objects and sort it however you might choose. Using parallel collections to store what are effectively the properties of objects is generally not the way to do things in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve what you're trying to do is to use a `GroupBy` expression.

```
  var s = "ddddbbcccaeeeee";
  
  var list = s.GroupBy(x => x)
              .Select(x => new { Char = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
              .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);

  foreach(var item in list)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(item.Char + " " + item.Count);
  }
```

The code treats `s` as a character array and counts instances of all characters. The `OrderByDescending` then sorts by `Count`.

The output of code below should look something like this:

```
e 5
d 4
c 3
b 2
a 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your LINQ statement is trying to sort each element in `usedCharacters` by an by a constant `int[]`. It doesn't do anything like matching up the elements of both arrays. It's exactly as if you are doing this:

```
usedCharacters = usedCharacters.OrderByDescending(i => 42).ToArray();
```

It just leaves the array in the same order.

If you have two separate list and you want to order the first based on the second then you need to use `Zip` like this:

```
usedCharacters =
    usedCharacters
        .Zip(characterCounts)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Second)
        .Select(x => x.First)
        .ToArray();
```

If you have the initial string of characters then this is the simplest way to get your result:

```
string characters = "ddddbbcccaeeeee";
char[] usedCharacters =
    characters
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
        .Select(x => x.Key)
        .ToArray();
```